# Determine the largest size of $n$

Tags: logarithms

If function $f(n) = \lg n$ (log of $n$ to base $2$), and assuming that the algorithm to
solve the problem takes $f(n)$ microseconds, what is the largest size of $n$ that can be solved in $1$ sec.?

To process $32$ items, it would take $5$ microseconds.

Comment: 1 second = 1 million micro seconds

Comment: I tried to this in excel and found that 10 to the power 308 items can be processed in 1023.154 micro seconds. Not sure if my calculation is correct or not

Comment: Then you need $f(n)=1,000,000$

Comment: TeX tip of the day: put commas in braces. "1{,}000{,}000" produces $1{,}000{,}000$.

Comment: Use $\large{\rm log}_{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the largest $n$ such that ${\hbox log}_2 n \leq 10^6$, since you are dealing with microseconds. You can raise both sides to the power of $2$ to solve.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by raising both sides to the power of 2. By the rules of logarithms, I came to the solution that 2 raised 1 million items can be processed in 1 sec.

Comment: It should be raise $2$ to the power of both sides, not the other way, which is squaring